$(p, q)$ tensors and multidimensional arrays
I am trying to understand connections between different interpretations of tensors. In many contexts, tensors are treated simply as multidimensional arrays.
Let us consider the following example. Let
$$\boldsymbol{A}=\left[\boldsymbol{A}_{:{,}:{,}1} \; \middle| \; \boldsymbol{A}_{:{,}:{,}2}\right]=\left[ \begin{matrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{matrix} \; \middle| \; 
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2
\end{matrix} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2 \times 2}.$$
Let $\boldsymbol{E}_{ijk} \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2 \times 2}$ denote a $2 \times 2 \times 2$ array that is $0$ everywhere except at the $(i, j, k)$ entry, which is equal to $1$. Then,
$$ \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2 \times 2} = \langle \boldsymbol{E}_{111}, \boldsymbol{E}_{121}, \boldsymbol{E}_{211}, \boldsymbol{E}_{221}, \boldsymbol{E}_{112}, \boldsymbol{E}_{122}, \boldsymbol{E}_{212}, \boldsymbol{E}_{222}\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$$
and
$$\boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{E}_{111} + 2 \boldsymbol{E}_{222}.$$
Let $V := \mathbb{R}^2 = \langle \boldsymbol{e}_1, \boldsymbol{e}_2\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$ and $V^* = \langle \psi_1, \psi_2 \rangle_{\mathbb{R}}$, where $\psi_{i}\text{: } \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by setting $\psi_i(\boldsymbol{x})=\boldsymbol{x}^T \boldsymbol{e}_i$. The set $\mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2 \times 2}$ is isomorphic to the set of $(p, q)$ tensors $V^{\otimes p} \otimes (V^*)^{\otimes q}$ whenever $0 \le p \le 3$ and $q=3-p$. Thus, $\boldsymbol{A}$ can be identified, e.g., with:
$$ \mathcal{A}_1:=\boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1+2 \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \in V \otimes V \otimes V, $$
$$ \mathcal{A}_2:=\boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \psi_1+2 \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \psi_2 \in V \otimes V \otimes V^*, $$
and
$$ \mathcal{A}_3 := \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \psi_1 \otimes \psi_1+2 \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \psi_2 \otimes \psi_2 \in V \otimes V^* \otimes V^*. $$
Regardless of the representation of $\boldsymbol{A}$, the essential information (the coefficients) is preserved.
However, there are differences when it comes to “multiplication” by a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For example, let us consider multiplication by $\boldsymbol{e}_1=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]^T$.

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is interpreted as $\mathcal{A}_1$ (i.e., as a $(3, 0)$ tensor), then $\mathcal{A}_1 \boldsymbol{e}_1$ is simply $\mathcal{A}_1$, as $\mathcal{A}_1$ is a constant.

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is interpreted as $\mathcal{A}_2$ (i.e., as a $(2, 1)$ tensor), then the evaluation of $\mathcal{A}_2$ at $\boldsymbol{e}_1$ leads to $$\mathcal{A}_2 \boldsymbol{e}_1 := \mathcal{A}_2(\boldsymbol{e}_1) = \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \psi_1(\boldsymbol{e}_1)+2 \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \psi_2(\boldsymbol{e}_1) \in V \otimes V \otimes \mathbb{R}.$$
This may further be simplified as $\mathcal{A}_2 \boldsymbol{e}_1 = \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes 1 $. As $V \otimes V \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong V \otimes V \cong \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, the result can be identified with the matrix
$$\boldsymbol{E}_{11}=\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}. $$

If $\boldsymbol{A}$ is interpreted as $\mathcal{A}_3$ (i.e., as a $(1, 2)$ tensor), then the evaluation of $\mathcal{A}_3$ at $\boldsymbol{e}_1$ leads to $$\mathcal{A}_3 \boldsymbol{e}_1 := \mathcal{A}_3(\boldsymbol{e}_1) = \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes \psi_1(\boldsymbol{e}_1) \otimes \psi_1(\boldsymbol{e}_1)+2 \boldsymbol{e}_2 \otimes \psi_2(\boldsymbol{e}_1) \otimes \psi_2(\boldsymbol{e}_1) \in V \otimes \mathbb{R} \otimes \mathbb{R}.$$ This simplifies to $\mathcal{A}_3 \boldsymbol{e}_1 = \boldsymbol{e}_1 \otimes 1 \otimes 1$. As $V \otimes \mathbb{R}\otimes \mathbb{R} \cong V = \mathbb{R}^2$, the result can be identified with the vector $$\boldsymbol{e}_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}\right] \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$


Thus, $\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{e}_1$ depends on the specific interpretation of the multidimensional array $\boldsymbol{A}$ as a $(p, q)$ tensor. To consider the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{A}$, one needs to interpret tensor-vector multiplication $\boldsymbol{Ax}$ as $\mathcal{A}_3 \boldsymbol{x}$, as the output needs to be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$. On the other hand, for example the Python library NumPy appears to calculate the tensor-vector product similar to the interpretation of $\boldsymbol{A}$ as $\mathcal{A}_2$:
import numpy as np

# Define the tensor:
A = np.zeros((2,2,2))
A[0, 0, 0] = 1; A[1, 1, 1] = 2

# Define the vector:
e1 = np.array([1, 0])

# Calculate the tensor-vector product:
print(np.tensordot(A, e1, axes=([0], [0])))

Therefore, the different interpretations of $\boldsymbol{A}$ do not appear to be equivalent.

(1) There is also $\mathcal{A}_4 := \boldsymbol{\psi_1} \otimes \psi_1 \otimes \psi_1+2 \boldsymbol{\psi_2} \otimes \psi_2 \otimes \psi_2 \in V^* \otimes V^* \otimes V^*$ (2) What is the Question here ? (3) This is not with Tensor only , It will occur with Matrix made of Vector.

@Prem (1) Yes. (2) How are the different interpretations of a multidimensional array as a (p, q) tensor, where $0 \le p \le 3$ and $q = 3-p$, equivalent? How should the array representation be interpreted? (3) Yes.

There is a canonical inner product $(x,y)\mapsto x^Ty$ which makes $V\cong V^$, so you can't really distinguish between them and this seems to be where your confusion is coming from. If you want to understand the difference between $V$ and $V^$ then you're better off with $V$ being some abstract vector space rather than $\mathbb R^n$.

Although a tensor can be represented by a hypermatrix (multidimensional array), you still need to account for the appropriate transformation rule for the type of tensor in question. They are not all equivalent. See this paper for a nice explanation.

A multidimensional array is not already a tensor. It becomes a tensor when we take the components $A_{ijk}$ and linearly combine them with the basis tensors $e_i\otimes e_j\otimes e_k$ or $e_i\otimes e_j\otimes \psi_k$ and so on. This leads in the case with three indices to eight different types of tensors for a single three dimensional array.

One of your interpretations is odd: when we "multiply" $e_i\otimes\psi_j\otimes\psi_k$ with an $e_\ell$ we have to say into which of the two possible slots this $e_\ell$ goes in. This is either $e_i\otimes\psi_j(e_\ell)\otimes\psi_k$ or $e_i\otimes\psi_j\otimes\psi_k(e_\ell)$ but I have never seen $e_i\otimes\psi_j(e_\ell)\otimes\psi_k(e_\ell)$ unless we explicitly say so.

@KurtG. I interpreted $e_i \otimes \psi_j \otimes \psi_k$ as a function $x \mapsto e_i \otimes \psi_j(x) \otimes \psi_k(x)$, since $\psi_i\text{: } V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a basis functional of the dual $V^*$.

No. $e_i \otimes \psi_j \otimes \psi_k$ is a trilinear map from $V^*\times V\times V$ to $\mathbb R,.$

@KurtG. Interesting. It appears that your viewpoint treats tensors as multilinear maps. I have studied tensors as elements of tensor product spaces, which are defined using the universal property. Anyways, my interpretation of $e_i \otimes \psi_j \otimes \psi_k$ is incorrect. However, would it be correct to treat $e_i \otimes \psi_j$ as a function from $V$ to $V \otimes \mathbb{R}$ such that $(e_i \otimes \psi_j)(x)=e_i \otimes \psi_j(x)$?

I'd say $e_i\otimes\psi_j$ can be considered to be  linear map from $V$ to $V,.$ Proof. When it eats a vector $v$ this can only happen in $\psi_j(v),.$ What comes out is the vector $e_i\psi_j(v)\in V,.$
